# How to show source code when debugging node against a remote process

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a nodejs app running in docker container in Linux.  I am using VSCode in Windows 10 to remotely debug it.  I successfully connect to the container and VSCode accurately displays remote logs in Debug Console.  If I **manually** add a 'debugger' statement in the node code (in published docker image) I get the correct break in VSCode. Then, and only then, can I add dynamic breakpoints to ONLY that js file.

The "LOADED Scripts" does not show/stream any other programs to my VSCode session.  The only thing I see are VMxxxxx scripts which are compressed, unreadable and unusable for adding breakpoints.

How do I get the code to stream down?  I understand it is read-only and that's all I care about.

My launch.json file contains the following config:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Remote QA",
    "port": 9229,
    "address": "11.222.333.444",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "remoteRoot": "/opt/myApp",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.
Rob

Comment: Anyone with ideas on getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The config MUST include:
{
"type": "node",
"request": "attach",
"name": "Attach to Remote QA",
"port": 9229,
"address": "11.222.333.444",
"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
"remoteRoot": "//opt//myApp//",
"protocol": "inspector",
"sourceMaps": false,
"init": "what-you-need-here-to-watch"
}